# Grab a number in between a varchar in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to grab a number by using SQL query. I need to grab the number before it says 'LEADS'

Sample of entry I might encounter:

`PDIP300MIL-14LEADS`

`QFN6X6-40LEADS`

`QFN6X6-240LEADS`

`WSOIC/16LEADS`

So as you can see the prefix can be any length. Also sometimes the delimeter is `/` or `-`. But it is fix that the suffix is `LEADS`.

On a sidenote. Other entries are like `ICL7665 BCSA` so it has no leads so it has to be skipped.

Edit: I am very sorry if I am not that clear. The one I am trying to grab is the number between the delimeter and Leads.

So in the four examples I am trying to grab: 14, 40, 240, 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like using `substring_index`

```
select 
  substring_index(
    substring_index(
       replace(col,'/','-')
      ,'LEADS'
      ,1),
    '-'
    ,-1
  )
from table1
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e59e5/5)

To skip entries you can filter result by using having clause

```
select 
  substring_index(
    substring_index(
       replace(col,'/','-')
      ,'LEADS'
      ,1),
    '-'
    ,-1
  ) num 
from table1
having num * 1 > 0
```

[`DEMO 2`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bae6/2)

Comment: Thank you just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '[0-9]+LEADS$'